# Creating a JBOSS-EAP-6 application on Openshift V3

Tags: openshift

I have been trying to migrate a jboss-eap-6 application from Openshift V2 to V3.

According to Openshift migrate guide, I should use "oc new-app --strategy=source" command then adds "eap64-openshift" or "jboss-eap-6" as image name. I failed with error message: "error: no match for jboss-eap-6" or "error: no match for eap64-openshift".

However, I have had no problem of using "wildfly" in place of image name.

Did anyone have experience of building jboss EAP6 application on Openshift V3 platform?

PS I did create a support case on REDHAT two months ago. The response I have got so far is: "it should work, but we don't know why it's not."

Comment: I finally got a word from Redhat technical support that Jboss EAP 6 was not a currently supported "image" on Openshift V3. I am wondering if anyone had any experience with Jboss EAP 6 on Openshift V3, or am I the only one who is having this difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Following the Openshift [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-jboss-eap), you should use :

```
oc new-app --strategy=source jboss-eap64-openshift~https://github.com/<github-id>/<repo-name>.git
```

So neither `eap64-openshift` nor `jboss-eap-6` but `jboss-eap64-openshift`